# How to make very simple http proxy using werkzeug or other python requests framework?

Tags: python, http, proxy, flask, werkzeug

Is it possible to setup a listener on say port 9090 and add a header, like Host: test.host to each request incoming on 9090 and send it on to say 8080?

Thanks

EDIT: I went with a reverse-proxy for now, applying the hostname:port to *any* request that comes in.

Comment: What prevents you from using an existing proxy, such as Apache's mod_proxy? Are there features not available in your web server that you need to implement?

Comment: @jd How can I make mod_proxy listen to various ports, not just the default apache port? Ive read that apache doesnt like to listen to many  anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Twisted has an implementation of a reverse proxy that you could modify to suit your needs. You can look at the examples [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples/). If you look at the source code of `twisted.web.proxy`, you can see that the 'Host:' header is set in `ReverseProxyRequest.process`, so you could subclass it and set your own header.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to tailor the proxied request based on parameters that only your web application can know (for example, you need to authenticate the proxied request with your webapp's custom authentication system), you should use your web server's proxy capabilities.

Example with Apache:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:9090
ProxyRequests off
<VirtualHost myhost:9090>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost myhost
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have to proxy things in a Flask or Werkzeug application, you can use httplib, creating requests based on the incoming request data and returning the response, either raw or modified (eg for link rewriting). It's doable, I have one such proxy in use where there was no good alternative. If you do that I recommend against using regular expressions to rewrite HTML links. I used PyQuery instead, it's far easier to get it right.

Comment: I need to add or set the header Host to a specific value, for a really bad legacy application that has a bunch of business logic around the hostname. But, to check how the application looks on mobile devices, and to make development/testing easier (running several instances on different ports fe), I want to setup this proxy-and-add-header before it.

Comment: Right now I have a virtual host setup and then I need to muck around with /etc/hosts, its just ugly. Making a small python script to which I can tell, hey listen on 9090 add host:header blah to any requests and forward them to localhost:7777 would be nice, then I could go to privateIp:9090 from phone and application would still think its being served from blah.

Comment: I see. Then small web app is probably the way to go. I guess @mensi's answer is the best one but you prefer Werkzeug over Twisted it shouldn't be very hard.